# increasing the row number using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, increment

I'm trying to increase the row each time around the loop, but it's not increasing is there something wrong with my JavaScript code?

```
var image= [];        
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    var avatar = test[i].image; // The profile image
    var row =5;

    if(i % 2 === 0){
        image[i]= Titanium.UI.createImageView({
            top:row,
            image:avatar
            });
        win.add(image[i]);
        //trying to increase the image
        row =row+200;
    } else if(i % 2 === 1) {
        image[i]= Titanium.UI.createImageView({
            top:row,
            image:avatar
            });
        win.add(image[i]);

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the edit you make it look cleaner :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't say I'm certain of what you're attempting to achieve, but at the beginning of your `for` iteration you're resting `row` to 5.  You should move your `var row=5;` declaration to the top with `var image[];`

You might also consider the short form `row+=200;`

Comment: can i answer one more question, you know with my loop, im trying to place every second image on the right, and the first one the left. its doing it okay for all rows, execept the first row, which in this case is '5' thanks

Comment: i will just ask another question

Answer (score 1):

try to move this line upper outside of the loop :

```
var image= [];        
var row =5;

for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing row in each start of loop. Try taking your var row = 5 outside of the loop:

```
var image= [];     
var row =5;   
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    var avatar = test[i].image; // The profile image

    ...
}
```